# Reverse of grouping in java 8

Tags: collections, java-8, grouping, java-stream, collect

I can group the list of students using the below lamda expression. The result would be grouping the student list grouped by "Department" and then grouped by "gender".

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Student>>> studentCatg = studentList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Student::getDepartment, groupingBy(Student::getGender)));
```

Now i need to get a Single List from the above MAP that should contain students of particular department. is there anything reverse of grouping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `EntrySet` for given department, combine `Map<String, List<Student>>` to `List<List<Student>>` by `map` to entry set value and then `flatMap` to a `List<Student>`, something like this:

```
String department = "department name";
List<Student> students = studentCatg.get(department)
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

#### Reverting to initial list

```
List<Student> students = studentCatg.values()
        .stream()
        .map(Map::values)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Just tweaked your post and got the answer. Thanks BTW.
    String department = "department name";
    List<Student> students = studentCatg.get(department).values.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: @june Yes, it can be simplified by taking `values` instead of `entrySet`, good catch! :)

Comment: is there a code to do a full reverse ? List to Map<String, Map<String, list>> by grouping. Now Map<String, Map<String, list>> to List ?

Comment: @june Do you mean a reverse to initial `studentList` list?

Comment: @june I've updated the answer to explain this case as well.

Comment: Perfect .. I have tried few, but not . let me dig some more in streams. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this entry when I was looking for a way to invert a groupingBy map but as I didn't find a common solution I constructed my own so just in case it is of interest.

```
public static <K, V> Map<V, List<K>> invertGroupByMap(final Map<K, List<V>> src)
{
    return src.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(a -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(a, e.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```